# Require.js loads the function (it exists in bundle.js), but console throws "not defined"

Tags: error, requirejs, requirejs-config.js

Having an issue with one of the plugins recently installed.

My DEV server and local DEV servers both are working normal, not throwing errors, but PRODUCTION server throws **"Uncaught ReferenceError: tmlsOwlCarousel is not defined"**.

Both PRODUCTION and DEV are running in the PRODUCTION mode. Local DEV runs in DEVELOPMENT mode.

Here is the code that executes it:

```
require([
'jquery',
 // tried DOM READY, didn't work.
'domReady!',
"Ves_All/lib/owl.carousel/owl.carousel.min",
'Ves_Testimonial/js/testimonial-carousel',
], function ($) {
    $( document ).ready(function() {            
    // tried to see if it ever loads the function - it doesnt
    //setInterval(function(){ console.log(typeof tmlsOwlCarousel); }, 1000);

    tmlsOwlCarousel("#testimonial-carousel-10199329431611963779", ".owl-carousel");
        $('#testimonials10199329431611963779 .tmls-readmorelink').click(function() {
            var parent = $(this).parents('.tmls-testimonial');
            $(parent).find('.tmls-excerpttext').hide();
            $(parent).find('.tmls-fulltext').fadeIn('slow');
        });
        $('#testimonials10199329431611963779 .tmls-item').mouseleave(function() {
            $(this).find('.tmls-excerpttext').fadeIn('slow');
            $(this).find('.tmls-fulltext').hide();
        });
    });
});
```

I have looked inside of the bundle.js file and that function exists and is being loaded.

I also tried onLoad / onReady / domReady and setInterval to see if that function ever loads, but it doesn't.

**bundle.js** file is about **2MB**, so I'm not sure if it's the file size or what is happening here.

Why would it never load if it does exist in the bundle file?

**UPDATE:**

The function that fails exists in: Ves_Testimonial/js/testimonial-carousel.js file. The file exists in the /static folder and is being loaded into the bundle.js

**UPDATE:**

requirejs-config.min.js also contains Ves_Testimonial/js/testimonial-carousel.js

```
(function () {
    var config = {
      map: {
        '*': {
          testimonial_fancybox: 'Ves_Testimonial/js/jquery.fancybox.pack',
          rating: 'Ves_Testimonial/js/rating',
          testimonial_rating: 'Ves_Testimonial/js/testimonial_rating',
          testimonial_carousel: 'Ves_Testimonial/js/testimonial-carousel',
          testimonialtowlcarousel: 'Ves_Testimonial/js/owl.carousel.min'
        }
      },
      shim: {
        'testimonial_carousel': {
          deps: [
            'jquery',
            'Ves_All/lib/owl.carousel/owl.carousel.min'
          ]
        },
        'Ves_Testimonial/js/carouFredSel': {
          deps: [
            'jquery'
          ]
        },
        'Ves_Testimonial/js/testimonial-carousel': {
          deps: [
            'jquery',
            'Ves_All/lib/owl.carousel/owl.carousel.min'
          ]
        },
        'testimonialtowlcarousel': {
          deps: [
            'jquery'
          ]
        }
      }
    };
    require.config(config);
  }) ();
```

Comment: This is probably an issue with javascript bundling itself, what are you using to do the bundling?

Comment: @MarkRees whatever is standard for Production deployment. The settings on backend admin section are hidden because it's in production mode.

Comment: I'm going to try deleting /static folder to see if fixes the issue.

Comment: Don't delete static's .htaccess file if you are using apache

Comment: Yup, I'm aware. Even if you run nginx it is also needed for things like Setup Wizard and Upgrades.